# Spring - SpringJUnit4ClassRunner still using LOG4J 1 instead of 2?

Tags: java, spring, maven, log4j, log4j2

I am using the `SpringRunner` class to guide my IT tests:

```
@ContextConfiguration(loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class, classes = MyTestConfiguration.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
class SomeTestIT {
    // tests here
}

@Configuration
public class MyTestConfiguration {
}
```

I have the following Maven dependencies for log4j2:

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

My `log4j2.xml` looks as following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration strict="true" monitorInterval="30" status="error">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%5p | %d | %F | %L | %m%n"/>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="error">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I have put this `log4j2.xml` in `src/test/resources`.

Now, when the tests are running, I get the following warnings:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

For some reason I cannot find, my log4j2 configuration is not being used for loggings from `SpringRunner`. How can I debug and hopefully fix this?

**update**

I do not think it is related, but just in case: I have also following dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is old log4j binding:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.25</version>
</dependency>
```

Here `slf4j-log4j12` states for slf4j over log4j v1.2

You should update your slf4j binding to

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Latest version is 2.9.1. Version earlier than 2.9.0 [doesn't match](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl) your SLF4J API version.

Comment: I will try that out. Should I leave `org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25` in classpath?

Comment: Yes. Especially if you plan to use slf4j yourself. I'm still trying to verify spring dependencies, but I wonder what version you are using.

Comment: Sorry. I see that it is 5.0.1

Comment: Spring 5 depends on slf4j-api-1.7.25 and log4j-api-2.9.1. So hope just updating binding will resolve it for you.